# Pushing to heroku timing out for compilation

Tags: git, heroku

Currently I've been getting this error everytime I try and upload my project. The repo size is only 800kb as it's just been inited, so it's not the size that's the problem. When I push it, it hangs for a good few minutes.

```
Abot::artifacts $ git push heroku master

 !  Timed out preparing your repository for compilation.
 !  If this happens consistently please see
 !  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#repo-size

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Even I am having same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is something wrong with Heroku right now.

https://status.heroku.com/